# Combine daily data into monthly data in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, date, pandas

I am trying to figure out how I can combine daily dates into specific months and summing the data for the each day that falls within the specific month.

Note:  I have a huge list with daily dates but I put a small sample here to simply the example.

File name: (test.xlsx)

For an Example (sheet1) contains in dataframe mode:

```
       DATE     51      52      53      54      55      56
    0  20110706 28.52   27.52   26.52   25.52   24.52   23.52
    1  20110707 28.97   27.97   26.97   25.97   24.97   23.97
    2  20110708 28.52   27.52   26.52   25.52   24.52   23.52
    3  20110709 28.97   27.97   26.97   25.97   24.97   23.97
    4  20110710 30.5    29.5    28.5    27.5    26.5    25.5
    5  20110711 32.93   31.93   30.93   29.93   28.93   27.93
    6  20110712 35.54   34.54   33.54   32.54   31.54   30.54
    7  20110713 33.02   32.02   31.02   30.02   29.02   28.02
    8  20110730 35.99   34.99   33.99   32.99   31.99   30.99
    9  20110731 30.5    29.5    28.5    27.5    26.5    25.5
   10  20110801 32.48   31.48   30.48   29.48   28.48   27.48
   11  20110802 31.04   30.04   29.04   28.04   27.04   26.04
   12  20110803 32.03   31.03   30.03   29.03   28.03   27.03
   13  20110804 34.01   33.01   32.01   31.01   30.01   29.01
   14  20110805 27.44   26.44   25.44   24.44   23.44   22.44
   15  20110806 32.48   31.48   30.48   29.48   28.48   27.48
```

What I would like is to edit ("test.xlsx",'sheet1') to result in what is below:

```
     DATE    51     52      53      54      55      56
   0 201107  313.46 303.46  293.46  283.46  273.46  263.46
   1 201108  189.48 183.48  177.48  171.48  165.48  159.48
```

How would I go about implementing this?

Here is my code thus far:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

df = pd.read_excel('thecddhddtestquecdd.xlsx')

def sep_yearmonths(x):
    x['month'] = str(x['DATE'])[:-2]
    return x

df = df.apply(sep_yearmonths,axis=1)

df.groupby('month').sum()

writer = ExcelWriter('thecddhddtestquecddMERGE.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: why don't you do it with excel alone? should it use python?

Comment: Yes, I am creating a program that automatically does multi linear regression based off specific data pertaining to  a range of dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if 'DATE' is a column of strings and not your index.

Example dataframe - shortened for clarity:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': {0: '20110706', 1:'20110707', 2: '20110801'}, 
                   52: {0: 28.52, 1: 28.97, 2: 28.52},
                   55: { 0: 24.52, 1: 24.97, 2:24.52 }
                   })
```

Which yields:

```
       52      55   DATE
0   28.52   24.52   20110706
1   28.97   24.97   20110707
2   28.52   24.52   20110801
```

Apply the following function over the dataframe to generate a new column:

```
def sep_yearmonths(x):
    x['month'] = x['DATE'][:-2]
    return x
```

Like this:

```
df = df.apply(sep_yearmonths,axis=1)
```

Over which you can then groupby and sum:

```
df.groupby('month').sum()
```

Resulting in the following:

```
          52    55
month       
201107  57.49   49.49
201108  28.52   24.52
```

If 'date' is your index, simply call `reset_index` before. If it's not a column of string values, then you need to do that beforehand.

Finally, you can rename your 'month' column to 'DATE'. I suppose you could just substitute the column 'DATE' inplace, but I choose to do things explictly. You can do that like so:

```
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: x[:-2])
```

Then 'groupby' 'DATE' instead of month.

Comment: I have tried implementing your code and have added it to the question above. My date column is not my index but when I try implementing the function what I get is     TypeError ('' 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'", u' occured at indexing 0')    this seems to be referencing     df = df.apply(sep_yearmonths,axis=1)

Comment: That's because your 'DATE' column is most likely a column of 'float', and not of string. You need to convert it to strings beforehand. Try replacing `x['month'] = x['DATE'][:2]` with `x['month'] = str(x['DATE'])[:2]`

Comment: hmmm I have tried this and the code it is compiling but it is not merging anything. when I print the df it results in the same exact df(above) that I had before the code implementation. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you are replacing df with the result of calling `apply`? Apply doesn't change the dataframe inplace, rather returns a copy of it, so you need to store it or else the results are vacuous... that's the only thing that comes to mind

Comment: I have tried setting a new df to the results of apply via `df2=df.apply(sep_yearmonths,axis=1)` then `df2=df2.groupby('month').sum()` 
After that printing df would result in the same look as original df. Would it be possible to test out my code and see what could possibly be the cause of this? I am currently trying to trouble shoot why this code is not implementing as I want it. Thanks

Comment: I have tested out your code with the df that you have created above. It seems to work fine, but i am trying to figure out how i can format my code similar to yours which I believe will solve the problem. even changing the date to string still causes some problems

Comment: Are all of the values in the '52', '55', etc. columns numeric? Maybe you're having problems with 'sum'ming things that aren't numbers. I think you could take your current situation and compose a new question, to attract attention - maybe someone else can help you further where I'm not seeing how

Answer (score 0):

Use [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timeseries-resampling)

```
import pandas as pd
myTable=pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
myTable['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(myTable['DATE'], format="%Y%m%d")
myTable=myTable.set_index('DATE')
myTable.resample("M").sum()
```

[image]